React Swiper Centering a Center Slide that changes in width
I have a requirement that the center slide in a carousel expands to show additional content. Presently, I have this codesandbox
available. The main requirements are:

Non-centered slides are minimized and show the image only.
The centered slide expands to show some text content.
Depending on the screen size, the slides shown are dynamic and the  slides at the boundaries should be partially visible.

It looks fine on the first render, however upon sliding/transitioning to the next/previous slide it seems to be pushed to the left and occasionally shifts randomly to the right. At the moment its not a smooth transition and shifts to the left then suddenly re-centering abruptly. I have already tried playing around with the observer and related parameters as well as adding some CSS to the active slide but I haven't been successful in resolving the issue.
At the moment it looks like this:


Let me know in case i miunderstood the question & your requirement.

Here are few changes I've made to make image center & load content centrally to the active slide. Based on your css here are proposed changes. I've removed your class css at some places & added classes provided by react swiper directly.
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* text-align: center; */
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#slider-wrapper {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#slider-img-wrapper {
  min-width: 232px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider-card {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#slider-card #slider-card--content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
  width: fit-content !important;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active #slider-card {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
}



Right now I just need to center the slide properly when sliding/transitioning to the next/previous slides smoothly.
